# Where do browsers load fonts from?

Tags: css, browser, fonts, webfonts

When browser needs a web font, where does the web browser look for the font apart from the `@font-face` rule in which font is uploaded on the website. Does it load from the operating systems font collection?

Answer (score 1):

The term "web font" generally refers to fonts that are designed for the web and loaded via `@font-face` only, since that is pretty much the only way you can access fonts from the web in your CSS.

Fonts that are installed on the user's device don't count as web fonts because they're installed locally. Web *safe* fonts are fonts that the author can reasonably assume to be installed on most if not all of the devices that they are targeting, but they're not necessarily the same thing as "web fonts".